# Removing livewallpaper.

Tags: uninstall

I can not seem to find any resources regarding the removal of livewallpaper, a google search yields nothing on the topic and I have been driven to ask you guys.

I have little knowledge of ubuntu or linux in general and I have some extreme anxiety coming here for answers to this mundane question. So be gentle?

Comment: How did you install livewallpaper?

Comment: Via terminal if i recall correctly.

Comment: Do you know exactly what you did?

Comment: Was it this?: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/live-wallpaper-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

If you installed it from the PPA like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install livewallpaper livewallpaper-config livewallpaper-indicator
```

**You should be able to remove it with:**

```
sudo apt-get remove livewallpaper livewallpaper-config livewallpaper-indicator
```

**Alternate method:**

Use ppa-purge to uninstall livewallpaper. First you need to install ppa-purge:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then run the following command if you installed livewallpaper from the daily ppa:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily
```

Or if you are using the stable version, run this:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-stable
```

Source Alternate method: https://answers.launchpad.net/livewallpaper/+question/214781

Comment: When I try the first method, the process just aborts after asking for confirmation, even if I confirm. What can I do?

Comment: first one worked for me.+1

Answer (score 0):

If none of @elder 's solutions worked, add --remove as seen below

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily/
```

you can also add ubuntu at the end:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-daily/ubuntu
```

This will throw an error and inform you of other relevant livewallpaper packages to uninstall. Helpful if you have the indicator installed like I did.